# Programmatically get Gmail storage usage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

**How can I get the storage usage of Gmail programmatically?** This value appears in two places, but I cannot find an API for it.

The main goal is to automatically log Gmail storage usage to a Google Sheet and graph the storage usage trend.

**What I've tried:**

1. [DriveApp.getStorageUsed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getStorageUsed()) does not include Gmail usage.
2. [Reports API (`gmail_used_quota_in_mb`)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts) is not available for consumer Gmail accounts (only G Suite)
3. Scraping [www.google.com/settings/u/0/storage](https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/storage?hl=en) is not possible because a log-in is required, even when spoofing cookies (probably detects a new device/IP address).

---

[image]

Comment: I also can't find any documentation or examples using the API. You may file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106) regarding this.

Comment: @abielita See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Not the programmatic answer I am looking for, but this is my manual work-around until I discover an API method:

1. Examine the source code for [google.com/settings/u/0/storage](https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/storage?hl=en)
2. Find exact bytes of usage embedded in JSON:

```
...
,[["Drive",["24004828","0.02 GB"]
]
,["Gmail",["4859735562","4.52 GB"]
]
,["Google Photos",["0","0 GB"]
...
```

3. Log that (4,859,735,562) into a Google Sheet, along with the current date/time

Using precise measurements of bytes and seconds, it should only take a few measurements to get an accurate trend. (And I don't need to scale this for multiple accounts.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Drive V2 API.

[`About: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about/get) returns   [`quotaBytesByService[]`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about) where you can filter service by name (e.g. *GMAIL*, in your case)

If you want to use the API, you have to enable [the advance API option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and [use it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

Note that [the version 3 does not give you the service breakdown](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about).